# Missing FFTW libraries

Tags: fortran, mpi, fftw, intel-fortran

I'm trying to compile a code written in fortran90/95 and I'm getting this error:

```
user:~> make
ifort -O3 -lmpi -L/opt/local/intel/fftw/lib -I/opt/local/intel/fftw/include -        I/opt/sgi/mpt/mpt-2.03/include -L/opt/sgi/mpt/mpt-2.03/lib -o /test module_param.o incompact3d.o mesure.o schemas.o derive.o spectral.o tools.o filtre.o parametre.o forcage.o navier.o convdiff.o viv.o slfft3d_shift.o poisson.o
slfft3d_shift.o: In function 'slfft3d_shift_':
slfft3d_shift.f90:(.text+0x587e): undefined reference to 'rfftw3d_f77_mpi_create_plan_'
slfft3d_shift.f90:(.text+0x58a3): undefined reference to 'rfftwnd_f77_mpi_local_sizes_'
slfft3d_shift.f90:(.text+0x58cd): undefined reference to 'rfftwnd_f77_mpi_'
slfft3d_shift.f90:(.text+0x58d9): undefined reference to 'rfftwnd_f77_mpi_destroy_plan_'
slfft3d_shift.f90:(.text+0x91ca): undefined reference to 'rfftw3d_f77_mpi_create_plan_'
slfft3d_shift.f90:(.text+0x91ef): undefined reference to 'rfftwnd_f77_mpi_local_sizes_'
slfft3d_shift.f90:(.text+0x9219): undefined reference to 'rfftwnd_f77_mpi_'
slfft3d_shift.f90:(.text+0x9225): undefined reference to 'rfftwnd_f77_mpi_destroy_plan_'
slfft3d_shift.f90:(.text+0x111e7): undefined reference to 'rfftwnd_f77_one_real_to_complex_'
make: *** [/test] Error 1
```

Here's the Makefile:

```
FC = ifort
OPTFC = -O3 -lmpi -L/opt/local/intel/fftw/lib -I/opt/local/intel/fftw/include -      I/opt/sgi/mpt/mpt-2.03/include -L/opt/sgi/mpt/mpt-2.03/lib/test : module_param.o incompact3d.o mesure.o schemas.o derive.o spectral.o tools.o poisson.o filtre.o parametre.o slfft3d_shift.o forcage.o navier.o convdiff.o viv.o

    $(FC) $(OPTFC) -o /test module_param.o incompact3d.o mesure.o schemas.o derive.o spectral.o tools.o filtre.o parametre.o forcage.o navier.o convdiff.o viv.o slfft3d_shift.o poisson.o

module_param.o : module_param.f90
    $(FC)  $(OPTFC) -c module_param.f90 incompact3d.o : incompact3d.f90
    $(FC)  $(OPTFC) -c incompact3d.f90 mesure.o : mesure.f90
    $(FC)  $(OPTFC) -c mesure.f90 spectral.o : spectral.f90
    $(FC)  $(OPTFC) -c spectral.f90 schemas.o : schemas.f90
    $(FC)  $(OPTFC) -c schemas.f90 derive.o : derive.f90
    $(FC)  $(OPTFC) -c derive.f90 tools.o : tools.f90
    $(FC)  $(OPTFC)  -c tools.f90 forcage.o : forcage.f90
    $(FC)  $(OPTFC) -c forcage.f90 navier.o : navier.f90
    $(FC)  $(OPTFC)  -c navier.f90 filtre.o : filtre.f90
    $(FC)  $(OPTFC) -c filtre.f90 parametre.o : parametre.f90
    $(FC)  $(OPTFC) -c parametre.f90 convdiff.o : convdiff.f90
    $(FC) $(OPTFC) -c convdiff.f90 poisson.o : poisson.f90
    $(FC) $(OPTFC) -c poisson.f90 slfft3d_shift.o : slfft3d_shift.f90
    $(FC) $(OPTFC) -c slfft3d_shift.f90 viv.o  : viv.f90
    $(FC) $(OPTFC) -c viv.f90
```

When I include the libraries required in the Makefile I get the following message:

```
user:~/test> make
ifort -O3 -lmpi -I/opt/local/intel/fftw/include -L/opt/local/gnu/fftw -        I/opt/sgi/mpt/mpt-2.03/include -L/opt/sgi/mpt/mpt-2.03/lib -I/opt/fftw/2.1.5.1/cnos/include     -L/opt/intel/composerxe-2011.0.084/mkl/include/fftw/fftw_f77.i -L/opt/fftw/2.1.5.1/cnos/lib     -I/opt/local/intel/fftw -I/opt/fftw/3.1.1/cnos/include -L/opt/fftw/3.1.1/cnos/lib -    I/usr/local/packages/nag/p3dfft-single/2.3/include -L/usr/local/packages/nag/p3dfft-    single/2.3/lib -o /home/u/guitar88/bin/teste module_param.o incompact3d.o mesure.o         schemas.o derive.o spectral.o tools.o filtre.o \
                    parametre.o forcage.o navier.o convdiff.o viv.o slfft3d_shift.o poisson.o -lm -L/opt/local/intel/fftw/lib -lsrfftw_mpi \
                    -lsrfftw -lsfftw_mpi -lsfftw
ld: cannot find -lsrfftw_mpi
make: *** [/test] Error 1
```

I'm using ifort compiler and I'm on a supercomputer environment working with MPI. Please, any clue of what is going on? Cheers.

Comment: Usually, `mpi` will create wrapper compilers (e.g. `mpif90`) around whatever compiler was used to compiler the mpi library.  I would use that rather than the compiler with the explicit flags.  Also, perhaps you need to `module load` the correct module to put the (parallelized?) fftw code on your LD_LIBRARY_PATH so that it can be found.

Comment: @mgilson Unfortunaly, mpif90 is not avaiable as a compiler. Also, as I'm working on a supercomputer, I can't 'sudo' anything, that means I can't make any alterations on the '$PATH'.

Comment: @LeonardodeAraujo -- You don't need `sudo` to alter your path.  That's something that is set up per user.  usually, on supercomputers, the compilers are set up by the system admins and you manipulate your various paths using the module command.  e.g. `module load intel` to load the intel compilers, etc, etc.  Usually you can check which modules are available by `module avail` and which modules you have pre-loaded using `module list`.

Comment: @VladimirF I included in the post what happens when I include this library.

Comment: @mgilson I see. So how can this be done? Yes, the code is parallelized. When I type `module avail` I get this:

Comment: MPInside/3.1 dot          module-info  mpt/2.03     perfboost    use.own
chkfeature   module-cvs   modules      null         perfcatcher
3.1.6                    modulefiles/dot          modulefiles/modules      modulefiles/perfboost
modulefiles/MPInside/3.1 modulefiles/module-cvs   modulefiles/mpt/2.03     modulefiles/perfcatcher
modulefiles/chkfeature   modulefiles/module-info  modulefiles/null         modulefiles/use.own
MPInside/3.1 dot          module-info  mpt/2.03     perfboost    use.own
chkfeature   module-cvs   modules      null                                            perfcatcher`

Comment: Is the library really in the path you supplied? I do not recognize its name, is it some old version?

Answer (score 0):

Pls attend that the linker tries to link against f77 mpi libs, whereas your source suffixes, e.g. of that "slfft3d_shift.f90" would imply you call f90 routines.

---

> on a supercomputer environment working with MPI

...you often have a system-specific convention which compiler to call by which wrapper; consult your system admin or the system faq on that.

Generally - it is quite uncommon trying to compile MPI apps without using MPI wrappers like "mpif90", "mpif90.mpich", "mpif90.openmpi" or similar.